# Problem with flexslider

Tags: theming, javascript

I have been searching everywhere for an answer to this. I created a views slide show, in Drupal 7, then found out it wasn't working with my responsive theme, so I followed a guide on how to install and use flexslide show modular. Everything worked great, in the preview it shows how it should look but once saved and viewed on website it is showing the nav arrows at the bottom together, not on side of slide show.

I have cleared cache, tried to edit using a css file, tried to move block to another region, tried to adjust size of images through styles, choose both styles and flex style in image format everything I have tried nothing works.

I can change the effects of the arrows, but I can not move them to where they should be. I have searched everywhere, but can not find anything on this problem or how to move them. I have included 2 screen shots of the preview in views and live site. Also, the address of the site i'm working on.

If someone could point me in right direction why this is happening would be great. Thanks!

prntscr.com/dhmdn4 **screen shot in views**
prntscr.com/dhmde7 **screen show of live site**

I know that the views shows arrows cropped or missing the top and my pager buttons not center, I can fix that with .css file I created to override my theme I am working on. I just can't figure out why the nav arrows are showing like that.

Comment: it does directly relate to Drupal, it is a Drupal modular. Please explain further.

Comment: The effect of `position: absolute;` and other CSS styles reported in the answer has nothing to do with Drupal, since Drupal doesn't change the effect of those CSS and other styles. The question is about plain CSS, at the end.

Comment: The question is also too broad, IMO. You cannot ask users to watch a site and tell you what could cause the effect you are seeing. Normal visitors can just guess things, since they cannot see the settings used from the site.

Answer (score 1):

remove the

```
/* position: absolute; */
/* bottom: 0; */
/* right: 0; */
```

from `.flex-direction-nav`

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thank you SO much. I have been pulling my hair out trying to track this down. I am old school when it comes to html and I have not fully picked up .css yet.

Comment: can you explain a little your answer?

Comment: My problem was I was looking in the flex slideshow css. My theme had a slideshow that I replaced with mine, so any changes I made to my flex slideshow was over ridden by my theme. It dawned  on me when looking looking for .flex-direction-nav in flexslider css, I used firefox dev tool to see it was in my theme css not flexslider css. As I said before I am VERY noobish to css

Comment: I am glad it helped you! Can you approve the answer ?

Comment: Sure if you tell me how. It seems they deleted your answer as my question doesn't relate to Drupal lol

Comment: I had same problem when I've first used the flexslider, but if they think it does not help people in the future and don't relate to Drupal ...

Comment: Nothing was deleted @lovs2build, the question just isn't on topic for our intentionally narrow scope so it was closed. Don't take it personally, it takes a while to get used to using Stack Exxhange sites, it needs a bit more thought to post questions here than other places (e.g. Support forums)

Comment: indeed it needs some time to get used with Stack Exchange